# HTML: Keeping h1 and h2 together

Tags: html, css, pdf, css-paged-media

I am using Oxygen XML Editor’s built in DITA XML to HTML with CSS transformation to create a paged-media output.
In each chapter, I want to start each section on a new page. To do that I added a css entry of:

```
h2 {
page-break-before: always;
}
```

But, when I do that, of course it puts a page break between h1 and h2. I want h1 and h2 to stay together on the first page of each new chapter, but I want each subsequent h2 to start on a new page.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish this in the css?

Thank you!
PJP

Comment: Is there a `div` around the `h2` and its following content?

Comment: Good morning. No there is not. Here is an example of h1:

Comment: Good morning. No there is not. Here is an example of h1:  `<h1 class="- topic/title title topictitle1" id="ariaid-title1"><span class="- topic/ph topic/title-wrapper ph title-wrapper">Preface</span></h1>`  and here is an example of h2: `<h2 class="- topic/title title topictitle2" id="ariaid-title2"><span class="- topic/ph topic/title-wrapper ph title-wrapper">Flight Operations Mission</span></h2>`.

Comment: Sorry, but is it `<h1>...</h1><h2>...</h2>...<h2>...</h2>...` or `<h1>...</h1><div><h2>...</h2>...</div><div><h2>...`?

Comment: I looked  at the HTML generated from one of Oxygen's DITA samples, and every `h2` is inside an `article`. Is that what you have?

Comment: Good morning, yes, the `h1` element is wrapped in `article` and each `h2` element is wrapped in `article`. The `h1` level wrapping wraps all the content in that chapter, meaning the closing tag comes after the last piece of content in the chapter, it is not limited to just wrapping the `h1` element.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could try breaking or not breaking per-article:

```
article {
  page-break-before: always;
}

article:first-of-type {
  page-break-before: auto;
}
```

Breaking on the `h2` would be a variation on that:

```
article h2 {
  page-break-before: always;
}

article:first-of-type h2 {
  page-break-before: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked on every chapter except Chapter 01...I need to look at the structure and see if there are differences (BTW, I used recommendation #2 above). Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: Hi Tony, so I went back and looked at my DITA. Chapter 1 is structured exactly like the rest, but h2 is not breaking like the other chapters to start of new page. Only thing I can think if is it may have something to do with it coming right after the front matter? Don't know why that would make a difference. The rest of the chapters are working fine. Any ideas? Thanks! Pat

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough information to help you. You could try looking at the HTML+CSS in a browser and use the browser's 'Inspect' (or similar) feature (usually available from the menu when you right-click on the page). Your browser might not support the `page-break-before` property, but even if it doesn't, it might be able to show the places where it is being set. Also, is your first chapter using exactly the same CSS files as your other chapters? Late thought: Oxygen also has a 'CSS Inspector' view that you can use to inspect the CSS for the HTML that it generated.

Comment: Hi Tony, it appears to me that the first chapter is structured the same. But, as a workaround, since the first chapter is really just some “front matter” type stuff, and only a few pages, I added an outputclass=“breakpage” to my source DITA for those sections and created a class in the css to break those. It’s good now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you.